# Implication of phrase "the only jokes"

Tags: only

I don't know what the following sentence means for sure: "The only jokes I tell are the ones that I hear from you."
Does it mean that "I don't tell so much jokes and the very jokes I tell, which is little in number, are mainly those I hear from you", stressing the number, or it doesn't implicate "little in number", but rather puts "completely" instead of "mainly"?
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker from the UK, I would interpret that as "The jokes I tell are exclusively the ones I hear from you." To infer the "little or few " meaning of only, you would need some additional quantifier, e.g. "I only tell a *few* jokes".

Comment: Slightly simpler: "The _few_ jokes I tell" does carry a connotation of not telling many jokes. But "The _only_ jokes I tell" does not carry that connotation.

Comment: Would agree (as a UK native) with both Jon and @Flatter that the principal meaning is about where the jokes come from. However, I feel there is a degree of implying _not that many_ about the phrase "_The only ..._". It's not that it _couldn't_ be used about something that happens a lot, more that (at least in my experience) it _most often_ gets used about something that doesn't happen _too_ often.